# Pull to refresh for StickyGridHeadersGridView

Tags: android

I am using StickyGridHeadersGridView in my project and I want to add pull to refresh functionality to StickyGridHeadersGridView. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pull to Refresh library https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh